# jquery select option after append operation

Tags: jquery, html-select

After appending the options.Is it possible to immediately select an option ..for example select option 3 immediately after appending in one single statement

```
  <Select class="yt"></select>

  var select = "<option val='1'>1</option><option val='2'>2</option><option val='3'>3</option>"
  $(".yt").append(select)
```

Comment: Yes, it is. What have you tried to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use .val()

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aqg6q/1/)

```
$(".yt").append(select).val('3');
```

**Updated after OP's comment**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aqg6q/2/)

```
var select = "<option val='1'>1</option><option val='2'>2</option><option name='sel' val='3'>3</option>"
$(".yt").append(select).val($('.yt option[name="sel"]').attr('val'));
```

Comment: You are choosing this by value right..What if i want to select it by the option name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.yt').val('3');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/Aqg6q/)

**Update**

you could make your own function

```
$.fn.select = function () {
    this.closest('select').val(this.val());
}
```

Then use it like

```
$('.yt option[name="test"]').select();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/Aqg6q/3/)

Comment: You are choosing this by value right..What if i want to select it by the option name..